# Is IndustrialCraft still compatible with the latest Minecraft version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I used to play with Industrialcraft through Technic all the time, and now that I'm playing Minecraft again, I went looking for it  however I can't find much up-to-date information.

Is Industrialcraft still in development and compatible with the latest version of Minecraft?

Comment: depends on what you mean by "similar". If you're not familiar with Thermal Expansion or RoteryCraft, check them out to see if either scratches the itch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version of IndustrialCraft called IC² which supports minecraft version 1.7.10. This means that it wont work with the newest version of Minecraft, but if you have an earlier installation of Minecraft version 1.7.10 or older, you can install it following this link which leads to the latest stable version.

> - [Download IC² for Minecraft 1.7.10](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Download#Download_IC.C2.B2_for_Minecraft.C2.A01.7.10)

However, the most popular and easiest way to play (and the way i would recommend doing it) is by installing a modpack-launcher, with the most popular right now being Feed-The-Beast or ATLauncher, where you get a bunch of different modpacks consisting of different mods made to fit together. There you can surely find a tech-modpack with IC² included. If you just want pure IC², in atleast ATLauncher (FTB needs to be confirmed) have the option to only include it and no other mods. Just follow link below to either ATL or FTB.

> - [Feed The Beast](http://www.feed-the-beast.com/)
> - [ATLauncher](https://www.atlauncher.com/downloads), just scroll down and select installation for your operating system

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if you are able to disable mods in FTB? I don't really want a bunch of random mobs running around messing with me

Comment: There should be a option do disable unwanted mods, yes, but i'm not 100 % sure. But i AM sure that there is in ATlauncher